# Why is React not checking my propTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have read [the official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and [the npm package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) for PropTypes.

However, when I run this code,

```
const propTypes = {
    foo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    bar: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    umu: PropTypes.string
};

const defaultProps = {
    umu: "default value"
};

class MyComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <ul>
            <li>foo is {this.props.foo}</li>
            <li>bar is {this.props.bar}</li>
            <li>umu is {this.props.umu}</li>
        </ul>
        );
    }
}
MyComp.propTypes = propTypes;
MyComp.defaultProps = defaultProps;

class MyWrapper extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComp bar="string and not a number"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyWrapper, null, null), document.getElementById("app"));
```

my `propTypes` are not checked, although the required property `foo` is not set and the property `bar` is not a number. Can anybody tell me what I do wrong?
Here's the corresponding [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Englandschorsch/pen/qXLJJL?editors=1011).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component will render even if it fails validation, this is more of a warning to the developer so you would see the error on the console. CodePen is not displaying those warnings, however, maybe because you're using the production version of react? Either way, this is correct behavior.

Comment: Two questions:

1. How can I choose the development version of react in CodePen? I am new to React and CodePen and merely picked React from the "Quick-Add" in the Pen Settings.

2. I get the same behaviour with my `create-react-app` project in Visual Studio Code. There are no warnings at all. Where should they appear anyway? In the terminal output while building? Do you have any further tipps for me?

Comment: I'm not sure about CodePen but no, the warnings appear at runtime on your browser console. Simply run your app and watch for those console errors in the browser